# Не убирается класс после отправки ajax

Tags: javascript, css

Не убирается стиль(подсветка обязательного поля) после отправки данных в файл обработчик, что не так делаю.
И еще вопрос, как подсветить textarea, потому что если пишу    `$('.input-box input, textarea').each(function()` не помогает((

я в js новичек, помогите пожалуйста.))

```js
$("#sendMail").on("click", function () {

    //создаем экземпляр класс FormData, тут будем хранить всю информацию для отправки
    var formData = new FormData();

    //присоединяем наш файл
    jQuery.each($('#file_v')[0].files, function(i, file) {
        formData.append('file_v', file);
    });

    //присоединяем остальные поля
    let name = $("#name").val().trim();
    let email = $("#email").val().trim();
    let tel = $("#tel").val().trim();
    let number_order = $("#number_order").val().trim();
    let message = $("#message").val().trim();
    let checkbox_check = $("#checkbox_check").prop('checked');

    //проверяем поля на заполнение
    if (name === '' || email === '' || tel === '' || number_order === '' || message === '' || !checkbox_check) {
        alert("Введите обязательные поля");
        $('.input-box input').each(function() {
            //подсвечиваем обязательные поля
            $(this).addClass('empty_field');
        });
        return false;
    }

    formData.append('name', name);
    formData.append('email', email);
    formData.append('tel', tel);
    formData.append('number_order', number_order);
    formData.append('message', message);
    

    //отправляем через ajax
    $.ajax({
        url: "assets/ajax/mail.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData, //указываем что отправляем
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#form_contact").prop("disable", true);
            $( ".loading_mail").show();

        },
        success: function(data){
            //стереть данные из инпутов
            $("#form_contact").trigger("reset");
            //убрать загрузачное окно
            $( ".loading_mail").hide();
            //////убрать подсветку//////////////
            $(this).removeClass('empty_field');
            //////***************////////////
            console.log(data);
            alert('Сообщение отправлено!');
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

```css
   
.input-box input.empty_field {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
}
```

```html
               <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
               <div class="col-lg-7">
                    <div class="comment-form">
                       <form id="form_contact" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="contact-one__form">  <!---->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="input-box has-feedback nameBlock">
                                        <label for="name" class="control-label ">Имя*</label>
                                        <input required type="text" id="name" placeholder="Иван Иванов" name="name" value="" class="" >
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <label for="email" class="control-label">Email-адрес*</label>
                                        <input required type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="" class="">
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="input-box _req">
                                        <label for="tel" class="control-label">Номер телефона*</label>
                                        <input required type="tel" id="tel" placeholder="+79997772255" name="tel" value="" class="">
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <label for="number_order" class="control-label">№ заказа*</label>
                                        <input required id="number_order" type="text" placeholder="0000000-я00" name="number_order" value="" class="">
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <label for="message" class="control-label">Сообщение*</label>
                                        <textarea required class="_req" id="message" name="message"
                                        placeholder="Сообщение" class="">
                                        </textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="file">
                                        <div class="file__item">
                                            <input type=file id="file_v" name="file_v" accept="image/*,video/*" class="file__input">
                                            <div class="file__button">Прикрепить файл</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="formPreview" class="file__preview"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <input required id="checkbox_check" checked type="checkbox" name="agreement" class="checkbox__input">
                                        <label for="checkbox_check" class="checkbox__label _error"><span>Я даю согласие на обработку персональных данных в соответствии с <a href="">Условиями</a>*</span></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12 text-left">
                                    <br>
                                    <button  id="sendMail" class="main-btn"> Отправить </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю вы забыли удалить стили в случае хороших данных там же где добавляете.

```js
$("#sendMail").on("click", function () {

    //создаем экземпляр класс FormData, тут будем хранить всю информацию для отправки
    var formData = new FormData();

    //присоединяем наш файл
    jQuery.each($('#file_v')[0].files, function(i, file) {
        formData.append('file_v', file);
    });

    //присоединяем остальные поля
    let name = $("#name").val().trim();
    let email = $("#email").val().trim();
    let tel = $("#tel").val().trim();
    let number_order = $("#number_order").val().trim();
    let message = $("#message").val().trim();
    let checkbox_check = $("#checkbox_check").prop('checked');

    //проверяем поля на заполнение
    if (name === '' || email === '' || tel === '' || number_order === '' || message === '' || !checkbox_check) {
        alert("Введите обязательные поля");
        $('.input-box input').each(function() {
            //подсвечиваем обязательные поля
            $(this).addClass('empty_field');
        });
        return false;
    } еlse {
        $('.input-box input').each(function() {
            //Убираем подсветку с обязательных полей
            $(this).removeClass('empty_field');
        });
    }

    formData.append('name', name);
    formData.append('email', email);
    formData.append('tel', tel);
    formData.append('number_order', number_order);
    formData.append('message', message);
    

    //отправляем через ajax
    $.ajax({
        url: "assets/ajax/mail.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData, //указываем что отправляем
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#form_contact").prop("disable", true);
            $( ".loading_mail").show();

        },
        success: function(data){
            //стереть данные из инпутов
            $("#form_contact").trigger("reset");
            //убрать загрузачное окно
            $( ".loading_mail").hide();
            //////убрать подсветку//////////////
            
            //////***************////////////
            console.log(data);
            alert('Сообщение отправлено!');
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

```css
   
.input-box input.empty_field {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
}
```

```html
               <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
               <div class="col-lg-7">
                    <div class="comment-form">
                       <form id="form_contact" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="contact-one__form">  <!---->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="input-box has-feedback nameBlock">
                                        <label for="name" class="control-label ">Имя*</label>
                                        <input required type="text" id="name" placeholder="Иван Иванов" name="name" value="" class="" >
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <label for="email" class="control-label">Email-адрес*</label>
                                        <input required type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="" class="">
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="input-box _req">
                                        <label for="tel" class="control-label">Номер телефона*</label>
                                        <input required type="tel" id="tel" placeholder="+79997772255" name="tel" value="" class="">
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <label for="number_order" class="control-label">№ заказа*</label>
                                        <input required id="number_order" type="text" placeholder="0000000-я00" name="number_order" value="" class="">
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="input-box">
                                        <label for="message" class="control-label">Сообщение*</label>
                                        <textarea required class="_req" id="message" name="message"
                                        placeholder="Сообщение" class="">
                                        </textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="file">
                                        <div class="file__item">
                                            <input type=file id="file_v" name="file_v" accept="image/*,video/*" class="file__input">
                                            <div class="file__button">Прикрепить файл</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="formPreview" class="file__preview"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <input required id="checkbox_check" checked type="checkbox" name="agreement" class="checkbox__input">
                                        <label for="checkbox_check" class="checkbox__label _error"><span>Я даю согласие на обработку персональных данных в соответствии с <a href="">Условиями</a>*</span></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12 text-left">
                                    <br>
                                    <button  id="sendMail" class="main-btn"> Отправить </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

По хорошему нужно смотреть каждое поле поскольку стиль нужно добавлять только на поле которое не ввели на не всё поля.